# JSON Schema validation for typos in JSON

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How to validate the schema properties for typos, when the property is not required value.

Ex JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

If the following is the JSON how can we catch the typo for "age" field which has typo as "aged".

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "aged": 21
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `"additionalProperties": false`, any properties not declared in `properties` will be considered an error. In more complex cases, you might need `"unevaluatedProperties": false` instead, but that's not necessary in this case. The other option is to be explicit about what you fields you allow with `"propertyNames": { "enum": ["firstName", "lastName", "aged"] }`.